# Unable to add drop-down navigation in action bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am unable to get how to add Drop-down navigation in the action bar in android studio. I have seen http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown and google for adding drop down navigation but don't get it. I am new to android-studio and android.

So when I run this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.activity_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener listener = new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, listener);
}
```

So problem is:

> When I run the application, it starts and closes itself within seconds without displaying anything.

[image: drop-down]

When I comment the last two lines then program works but if I uncomment them app starts and closes itself. Also the last two statements are deprecated.

From Logcat I founded:

```
02-06 12:24:20.809  18210-18210/com.mycompany.dropdown E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.dropdown/com.mycompany.dropdown.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
          at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.mycompany.dropdown.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
          at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
```

and more errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your code here to check what's happening, but this code worked for my:

```
   SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.activity_array,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); //or getSupportActionBar() depending on your target version

    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener listener = new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

            return false;
        }
    };

    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, listener);
```

TO make this working you have to take care of the action bar library that is being used. Here you can check which library you need and the code to get it. It also includes an example of navigation drop-down :
[developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: I have used your code but when I run the app, it start and closes within seconds automatically, I have edited the post...

Comment: I think I know what happened, I used android annotations so i have'nt used findByView, you should include mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById((R.id.left_drawer));

Comment: I added it, you have to put it in your activity layout and where RelatedLayout section is, you have to add your current content

Comment: Which android annotations did you used, if I don't want to use DrawerLayout and ListView?

Comment: The drawer layout and listview are other way to do what you want, it is to have a hiden panel on the left that you can show by sliding from the left to right, if you dont want you can delete that. YOu can use that or a spinner in the action bar. That's not a problem if they are deprecated. But this error is because you have some object that is null. Could you check if  after ActionBar bar = getActionBar();  the value of bar is not null?

Comment: I checked by: `if (bar == null) Log.d("Problem", "YES")` and found that bar is null, now what to do?

Comment: Is your activity extending ActionBarActivity , ActionBarSherlockActivity or your app uses as a theme Holo?

Comment: Use ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); if you use ActionBarActivity

Comment: Then i got this error: `Error:(28, 44) error: incompatible types
required: android.app.ActionBar
found:    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and when I resolved this then again my app starts and close itself..

Comment: I think it's a problem of you action bar, check this page where explains the library compatibility for actionbar http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html and make sure that the appcompat is the correct and you have as a theme the apppcompat <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >. Also at the end of the page is an example of a navigation drop-down

Comment: Thanks a lot, finaly worked I want you to modify your answer discussing this stuff, so I can accept it

Comment: ok, Did it worked when you added the theme? or have changed the appcompat?

Comment: NO my theme is: `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>` I didn't changed it just modified code where I was using ActionBar I used android.support.v7.app.ActionBar... :)